# Eigen::Ref in pass-by-pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, eigen

Similar to question [Pointer vs Reference difference when passing Eigen objects as arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030332/pointer-vs-reference-difference-when-passing-eigen-objects-as-arguments)

Let's say we have foo1 and matrix mat2by2:

```
void foo1(MatrixXd& container){
    //...container matrix is modified here
}
```

and

```
Matrix33d mat2by2;
mat2by2 << 1,2,
           3,4;
```

After reading http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html, it seems like a better alternative to foo1 may be:

```
void foo2(Ref<MatrixXd> container){
    //...container matrix is modified here
}
```

If foo2's parameter is being passed as a reference, 
what would be the equivalent to pass-by-pointer using the Eigen::Ref class??

```
void foo(Eigen::MatrixXd* container){
    //...container matrix is modified here
}
```

Comment: have you tried it? it's seem right, did you find any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the basic idea is *not* to use pointers or references directly. Eigen uses template expressions to represent calculations. This means the type changes depending on the expression used to calculate the matrix, and expressions are potentially carried around unevaluated.

If necessary Ref will evaluate the template expression into a temporary object matching the memory layout you requested to pass as an argument. If the memory layout of your argument matches the memory layout required by your parameter, Ref will act as a transparent reference.

Borrowing directly from the documentation: Your input parameters should be declared constant, while non-const parameters can be used as output parameters.

```
void cov(const Ref<const MatrixXf> x, Ref<MatrixXf> C)
{
   ...
   C = ...; // Your return value here
}
```

If you read from and write to a matrix, the parameter should also obviously be non-const.

For optional parameters you could use a pointer to a Ref.

Edit: The documentation does note that you can use constant references directly to pass parameters. This only works because the compiler is happy to convert temporary objects to const-references. It will not work for pointers.

Comment: About the edit: So, in the case that one passes a fixed-size matrix to a function taking a constant fixed-size matrix parameter, using Ref<> is really equivalent to a "direct" pass-by-reference, right? There shouldn't be any temporaries being evaluated (?)

Comment: If you use a non const Ref, then no temporary will occur. If one would be needed because of memory layout mismatch, then it won't compile. A const Ref, is like a c++ const reference, meaning that a temporary will be created if the memory layout don't match.

Comment: I think things got unclear there. According to the docs if necessary Ref _will_ create a temporary object. A template expression _will_ be evaluated into a temp. If it can though it will transparently reference rather than using a temporary.

const MyType& has different more limited semantics than that. It won't for example convert a double Matrix into a float Matrix. The compiler _is_ happy to evaluate a template expression to a temporary though (hence the constant reference).

Comment: I think the takeaway is use templates or Ref for most flexibility. If you understand the caveats though const& is also useable. Pointers are out though unless you want to manually force evaluation into a temporary matching your argument type exactly before taking the address.

Comment: I am wondering if this deserves to be discussed on a separate question. My question has been answered. However, it seems like there are cases where a Ref parameter is equivalent to a & parameter for some specific arguments...

Comment: For instance, think about a case where the argument WILL always be Matrix2d. It seems to me that the fun parameter can then be (read-only)={const Matrix2d&, const Ref<const Matrix2d>}, (writeable)={ Matrix2d&, Matrix2d*, Ref<Matrix2d>}.

My understanding is that in the cases where & or Ref<> is used, for this particular scenario no temporaries will occur (b/c of what ggael said, there no memory layout mismatch). In such case, there is really no difference between Ref and &.

Comment: I think you're exactly right there. If you can guarantee you will always have a Matrix2d then you can reference it / take its address without issue.